# Product matrix-vector using MPI (C) - doesn't work properly

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, vector, mpi

hopping you and your family are doing great concedering the situation.

I'm working on a program to multiply a matrix and a vector, using multithreading (MPI) in C. Here it is :

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int rank, size;

int mat[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
int vector[3] = {7, 8, 9};
int vecRes[3] = {50, 122};

int nbLigMat = sizeof(mat) / sizeof(mat[0]);
int nbColMat = sizeof(mat[0]) / sizeof(int);

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

int sendbuf[sizeof(vector) / sizeof(mat[0])], recvbuf, recvcounts[size];

if (size == nbColMat)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nbLigMat; i++)
        sendbuf[i] = mat[i][rank] * vector[rank];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        recvcounts[i] = 1;

    MPI_Reduce_scatter(sendbuf, &recvbuf, recvcounts, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank < nbLigMat)
        printf("Processeur num %d / outputVector[%d] : %d\n", rank, rank, recvbuf);
}
else
{
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("Le nombre de processeurs necessaires est : %d\n", nbColMat);
    }
}

MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

It does work for the following matrix/vector couples : 
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} and {5, 6}; {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} and {7, 8, 9}; {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}} and {9, 10, 11, 12} but for example with {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} and {10, 11, 12}, the result should be {68, 167, 266} but my output vector is {68, 167, 476}.

I realised that, I don't know for which reason, the elements in my input vector are changed between the beginning and the first for loop for each process even though i don't interact with it :

In process 0, my input vector became a {40, 11, 12} in the first loop and a {40, 280, 12} at the end. In process 1, {55, 11, 12} and then {55, 88, 12}. In p2, {72, 11, 12} and then {72, 108, 12}. These numbers match the result numbers of the mat[i][rank]*vector[rank] calculation in the first loop, but I don't understand how they get in my input vector.

Maybe i understood something wrong on how MPI works but i don't manage to find out how those number get there and overwrite my input vector. Hopping the explanation is clear enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in the dimension of sendbuf. If I run your example with {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} and {10, 11, 12} then:

```
sizeof(vector) / sizeof(mat[0]) = 1
```

which is too small, e.g. in your loop you assign values to sendbuf from i = 0 to i = nbLigMat-1.

If I replace the definition of sendbuf to be:

```
int sendbuf[nbLigMat], recvbuf, recvcounts[size];
```

then I get the correct answer:

```
Processeur num 0 / outputVector[0] : 68
Processeur num 1 / outputVector[1] : 167
Processeur num 2 / outputVector[2] : 266
```